# How to work Javascript API Atlassian Bitbucket?

Tags: bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I am successfully using [AP.require](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/jsapi/request/) ('url' ..),
url: api.bitbucket.org/2.0/,

but I don’t understand how to work with these [javacript api bitbucket](https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/docs/5.6.2/reference/js-api.html) modules and how they interact with bitbucket.
For example:
https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/docs/5.6.2/reference/javascript/bitbucket_util_navbuilder.html

Where to get 'bitbucket / util / navbuilder' and what is it for?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? what did you try?